# jQuery muddle: form that loads a form, that then loads another form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Ive gotten myself into a bit of a muddle, with a solution that half works.

Basically I'm using a basic `.load()` attached to a `<select>` to pull another form with a `<select>` populated through PHP/MySQL. What I then want is this newly loaded `<select>` to then load another form that is again populated through PHP/MySQL. When the user changes either of the `<select>`'s the changes need essentially move down the stack so to speak.

At the moment it works when an option is selected and a `.change()` is fired off, works perfectly fine. The problem is the initial loading of the second `<select>`, im not sure how to fire off the `.load()` I want.

The current version is here:
http://kick.hooplahosts.co.uk/fire/FireServiceProject/bag.php

and the offending forms are on the left (level, number and items), you an see the multi select doesn't load of first load or refresh, or even when the bag level is changed, it takes an actual selection in the bag number to do what i want it to.

I've edited out most of the unrelated html, and the scripts are a bit 'work in progress'

### HTML

```html
 <form action="php/bagCreate/newBag_bag.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <h2>Select Bag Level</h2>
    <select id="target" class="get" name="bagLevel">
      <option>Level 1</option>
      <option>Level 2</option>
      <option>Level 3</option>                                
    </select>        
 </form>            

<div id="upForm">
  <label>Bag Number</label>
  <form action="php/bagCreate/getContents_bag.php" method="post">
     <select id="target" class="getContents" name="bagNumber">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
     </select>        
  </form>

  <div id="upFormContents">
  <form>
  <label>Items in Bag</label>
     <select id="select2" class="input-large" multiple="multiple" size="20">
        <option>dsfgdsg</option>
        <option>dsfgdsgdfgfd</option>
    </select>        
  </form>
```

### JS

```js
$(document).on("change", "select.getContents", function(){
  var action = $('select.getContents').parent().attr('action');        
  fillContents(action)    
});

$(document).on("ready", "select.getContents", function(){
  var action = $('select.getContents').parent().attr('action');        
  fillContents(action)
});  

function fillContents(action){        
   $('#upFormContents').load(action,    
   $('select.getContents').parent().serializeArray());
}
```

Comment: OT: I read the topic title and thought of inception .. a form within a form within a form .. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the change event when loading the second `<select>` with `trigger('change');`

In your case e.g:

```
$('.getContents').trigger('change');
```

Be sure to trigger the second select with this code, when you are changing the first select (bag level).

Comment: Worked perfectly, stuck it inside the PHP file that contained the second form and works exactly how I imagined it. Thank you.